# How does React.suspense "handle" i18next backend loading?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm working with some pretty standard create-react-app boilerplate, which uses lazy loading and react-i18next as a translation library. This library uses i18next-http-backend to fetch the translation files from a remote API.

What i'm trying to understand, is how exactly React.suspense is able to "recognize" this asynchronous call, and show the fallback UI until it's done.

Index.ts file:

```
import "./i18n";//Notice this

  const container = document.getElementById("root");
  ReactDOM.render(
    <StylesProvider jss={jss}>
      <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
        <React.StrictMode>
          <BrowserRouter>
            <Router />
          </BrowserRouter>
        </React.StrictMode>
      </ThemeProvider>
    </StylesProvider>,
    container
  );
```

i18n file:

```
i18n
  .use(Backend)
  .init({
    backend:{
      loadPath: 'https://someRemoteApi/dictionary',          
   })
```

Router:

```
const Home = lazy(() => import("../../modules/home/Home"));
const Router: React.FC = (props) => {
  return (
    <>
      <ErrorBoundary>
        <Suspense fallback={<div className={styles.loader}><Loader /></div>}>
            <Switch>
              <ProtectedRoute exact component={Home} path="/"/>   
               ...more routes           
        </Suspense>
      </ErrorBoundary>
    </>
  );
};
```

With this setup, to my amazement, **the fallback  is rendered on the screen**, until this backend plugin finishes its job. I'm trying to understand the mechanics of it, and **whether this can be leveraged for other async operations**.

the React docs clearly state:

> React.Suspense lets you specify the loading indicator in case some
> components in the tree below it are not yet ready to render. Today,
> lazy loading components is the only use case supported by
> <React.Suspense>:

Any clarification will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The idea of `Suspense` is when a component throws a `Promise` (or anything that is called during the component’s render), `React` looks for the closest `Suspense` in order to display the fallback UI.

In your case, your components are using the `useTranslate` hook. When `namespaces` are not yet loaded, it throws a `Promise` and loads the `namespaces`. During the render phase, React catches the thrown `Promise` and looks for the closest `Suspense` component up the tree in order to display fallback UI.

This is a snippet from the hook `useTranslation`:

```
 // not yet loaded namespaces -> load them -> and trigger suspense
  throw new Promise((resolve) => {
    loadNamespaces(i18n, namespaces, () => {
      resolve();
    });
  });
```

You can check how the hook `useTranslation` works from [here](https://github.com/i18next/react-i18next/blob/master/src/useTranslation.js)

Comment: Thank you. Do you think it's "safe" to use this technique for other async operations, needed before the route is rendered?